# How can it be possible that my Cuda Vector is empty after just filling it?

Tags: c++, cuda

So I have this chunk of Code which is meant to be a plugin of a library for a future unity Asset. The library fills a mesh with tetrahedrons using a set of tridimensional points. I pass the points from Unity and everything works just fine the vector apparently fills up,or so says my log textfile...After the writting,before I try to call the tetraedralization method I check for the vector not to be empty and it turns out that it is empty. I Do not understand.

I never used dll communication so I am a bit lost.
Thank you for your time.

Here is the code:

```
extern "C"{
const int deviceIdx     = 0; 
const int seed          = 123456789;
const int pointNum      = 15000;
const Distribution dist = UniformDistribution;

Point3HVec   pointVec; 
GDelOutput   output; 

EXPORT_API void makeInputFromMeshCoords(float x[] , float y[], float z[],int sizeOfArrays){
     CudaSafeCall( cudaSetDevice( deviceIdx ) );
     CudaSafeCall( cudaDeviceReset() );
    std::ofstream StatisticsFile;
    StatisticsFile.open ("E:/documentos/Videojuegos/Cuarto_curso/TFG/SimplestPluginExample/Unity Project Plugin/Assets/Logs/CoordinatesUnity.txt"); 

    for(int i =0; i<sizeOfArrays;i++)
     {            

          Point3 point = {x[i],y[i],z[i]};
          pointVec.push_back(point);
          StatisticsFile <<"("<<pointVec[i]._p[0]<<","<<pointVec[i]._p[1]<<","<<pointVec[i]._p[2]<<")"<< std::endl;     
          StatisticsFile<<pointVec.size()<<std::endl; 
    }
    StatisticsFile<<"END OF LOOP; SIZE: "<<pointVec.size()<<"Empty " << (pointVec.empty()?"it is":"it is not")<<std::endl; 
    StatisticsFile.close();

    assert(pointVec.empty());
    GpuDel triangulator; 
    triangulator.compute( pointVec, &output );
}
```

}

Here are the library type definitions:

```
typedef thrust::host_vector< Point3 >    Point3HVec;
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `assert` is an expression you assert to be true under proper operation. You assert that the vector is empty, which fails, since it is in fact populated. Remove the `assert` or change it to `assert(!pointVec.empty());`.